# Does oracle client 12c requires Java on windows

Tags: oracle, installation, java

if I install Oracle 12c client on window server, does it get Java installed?

can we install oracle driver/client without Java?

Answer (score 2):

Oracle Client - the "thick" one - has own JRE embedded, it is used to run GUI management tools. If you do not need it, download and install Oracle (thin) Instant client

Answer (score 1):

Sure. You have to install JDK current version. You may also have to install ODAC to run ORACLE in Windows. I must say that it is a little bit hard to run ORACLE in windows.